# How to access values from your own settings page in javascript?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, javascript, options

I added may own settings page for my plugin with php. Furthermore I need to access the values from two inputFields from the settings page after someone clicks on a submit button on the public page. My click action for the submit button is a javascript file.

There is just the error, that the element can't be found.

Code to get the value:

```
var kasUser = document.getElementById("kasUserName").innerHTML
var kasPas = document.getElementById("kasPsw").innerHTML
```

Code from the settings page:

```
function JG_SiteEditor_settings_page() {
?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2>JG SiteEditor API Settings</h2>

<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields( 'JG-SiteEditor-settings-group' ); ?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'JG-SiteEditor-settings-group' ); ?>
    <table class="form-table">
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Kasserver API Benutzername</th>
        <td><input type="text" name="userName" id="kasUserName" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('userName') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr valign="top">
        <th scope="row">Kasserver API Passwort</th>
        <td><input type="password" name="password" id="kasPsw" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('password') ); ?>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <?php submit_button(); ?>

</form>
</div>
<?php
```

}

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the value of the element rather than the content.

```
var kasUser = document.getElementById("kasUserName").value;
var kasPas = document.getElementById("kasPsw").value;
```

You can check the content of your inputs by adding `alert(kasUserName);` and `alert(kasPas);`

Comment: Obviously you need to make sure your JavaScript file is enqueued properly.  I find it easier and neater to use jQuery rather than native JavaScript.  I wrap everything if a  `$( document ).ready(function() {} ` function.